# setAttribute method for source model

Tags: adminhtml

I added a custom attribute to customer entity with a custom source model in which I defined my `toOptionArray` method but when I open the customer to edit, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Namespace_Module_Model_System_Config_Source_Customer_AllowedPaymentMethods::setAttribute() in /home/ashfame/www/domain.lo/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php on line 389
```

What's `setAttribute` method supposed to do? I don't see it being defined in any other source model file in core? Should I be extending my class with some abstract class, then again all core source models don't extend from any class. What piece am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"then again all core source models don't extend from any class"
```

But they do. They extend the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`. And your class should extend that also. Take a look at `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean` for example.

Comment: Ah yes, I must have looked at the wrong place and judged too quickly, thank you!